# how to use vue.js in simple web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am gonna planning to use vue.js in a web application. but it could not loaded and not fired html in browser. Please look at my below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
```

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});

</script>

```
&#060;/head&#062;
```

<body>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: try to put your ``<script>`` inside ``<body>``?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to create Vue instance before vue.js is loaded, so I think if you put your code after vue.js, your application will work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```